# Easier way to forward ports

Tags: linux, networking

I was wondering if there is a simpler way to forward data through my DSL modem and router to my server without forwarding each port individually?  While still maintaining security.

Comment: Some routers come with a feature that lets you put an ip in "DMZ" mode, so that all unsolicited inbound traffic that doesn't match a NAT forward rule, gets forwarded to the IP. usually a DMZ is behind the firewall, but in front of the NAT, but depends on hardware implementation. look up your router to determine if it supports a DMZ. heres the netgear support for some of their models: http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1118/~/how-to-make-a-dmz

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible options that are entirely dependent on what your router supports.

### Forwarded Port Grouping, aka Custom Services

Many routers/modems support forwarding ports in groups with a given service name. Usually this option is labeled "Custom Services" in the router.

For instance, if I have a service/program that requires me to forward ports 1, 10, and 700 I can create a group titled "My Service" and include those ports. Then assign the group to an IP, and all ports in that group are forwarded there.

### UPnP

[Universal Plug-N-Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) allows you to manage a network device using a standardized protocol. There are many port fowarding management tools that operate over UPNP, but your router must support it.

Many applications have UPnP functionality built in, that automagically fowards the ports necessary for it work, but this varies from application to application.

Some examples would be [UPNP PortMapper](http://upnp-portmapper.sourceforge.net/) or [Application Port Mapper](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/application-port-mapper-the-easy-way-to-forward-ports.82109/).

Comment: Good points. Note that many consider UPNP to reduce the security of a given network, due to protocol and hardware exploits. it also gives malicious clients (trojans executing within your network) a new set of very dangerous tools for infiltrating your network. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#Problems_with_UPnP

Comment: @FrankThomas This is true. A good solution would be temporarily turning on UPnP to do your port fowarding work, then turning it back off. Ultimately port fowarding is tedious, but only-have-to-do-it-once work.